# Submit button doesn't appear

Tags: php, wordpress, header, submit

I was trying to make a pop-up with a signup form.

I have this script that works fine, if it's tested with a single page. But If I use it with 
my wordpress theme, i placed it in the header.php, the submit button doesn't appear and email textbox is shorter.

Image 1: It's OK. http://sdrv.ms/Ysgfmw
Image 2: Script in the wordpress template. http://sdrv.ms/10a3PpU

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks for the help.

Note: I omitted the complete urls.

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--*************** INICIO JAVASCRIPT/CSS EVILPOPUP     ************-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="......../evilpopup.js"></script>
    <link href="........./classic-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
        #mc_embed_signup
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
            display: none;
            z-index: 10000;
        }

        #mc_embed_signup form
        {
            position: fixed;
            top: 10%;
            left: 50%;
            width: 50%;
            margin-left: -25%;
            font: normal 100% Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            border: none;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #000;
            text-align: left;
            max-height: 400px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        #mc_embed_signup a.mc_embed_close
        {
            background: transparent url(http://downloads.mailchimp.com/img/closebox.png) no-repeat;
            display: block;
            height: 30px;
            width: 30px;
            text-indent: -999em;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <!--*************** FIN JAVASCRIPT/CSS EVILPOPUP     ************-->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hola</h1>
    <!-- Begin EVILPOPUP MailChimp Signup Form -->
    <div id="mc_embed_signup">
        <form action=".................us5.list-manage2.com/subscribe/post?u=3e03d112fc6fe9e6e2d643fa4&amp;id=28e366ba2d" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
            <h2>Gratis $3.000 en tu primera compra</h2>
            <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indica requerido</div>
            <div class="mc-field-group">
                <label for="mce-EMAIL">
                    Email  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
            </div>
            <div class="mc-field-group">
                <label for="mce-FNAME">Nombre </label>
                <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
            </div>
            <a href="#" id="mc_embed_close" class="mc_embed_close">Cerrar</a>
            <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display: none"></div>
                <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display: none"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
                <input type="submit" value="Suscribeme" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!--End EVILPOPUP mc_embed_signup-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the max-height

```
#mc_embed_signup form{
   position:fixed; 
   top:10%; 
   left:50%; 
   width:50%; 
   margin-left:-25%; 
   font:normal 100% Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; 
   font-size:14px; 
   border-radius:4px; 
   border:none; padding:10px 20px; 
   background-color:#fff; 
   color:#000; 
   text-align:left;
   max-height:500px;
   overflow-y:auto;
   overflow-x:hidden;
 }
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I changed it to 800 and still same height.

Comment: Now the buttom showed up, but still the textbox it's different size. It's strange. What's causing it? http://sdrv.ms/11nhupX

Comment: `.button { width: 150px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; }` put this in your style. play with the with you want.

Comment: No results!! Still having trouble the email length and the button.